# How to debug the error message from a yapf formatting task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yapf, lib2to3

I recently inherited a code base and am in the process of using yapf (and indirectly lib2to3) to format the code base. When I run the formatter I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/yapflib/yapf_api.py", line 183, in FormatCode
    tree = pytree_utils.ParseCodeToTree(unformatted_source)
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/yapflib/pytree_utils.py", line 125, in ParseCodeToTree
    tree = parser_driver.parse_string(code, debug=False)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib2to3/pgen2/driver.py", line 103, in parse_string
    return self.parse_tokens(tokens, debug)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib2to3/pgen2/driver.py", line 71, in parse_tokens
    if p.addtoken(type, value, (prefix, start)):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib2to3/pgen2/parse.py", line 119, in addtoken
    ilabel = self.classify(type, value, context)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib2to3/pgen2/parse.py", line 175, in classify
    raise ParseError("bad token", type, value, context)
lib2to3.pgen2.parse.ParseError: bad token: type=58, value='ִ', context=('', (325, 19))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/__init__.py", line 225, in _FormatFile
    reformatted_code, encoding, has_change = yapf_api.FormatFile(
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/yapflib/yapf_api.py", line 96, in FormatFile
    reformatted_source, changed = FormatCode(
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/yapflib/yapf_api.py", line 186, in FormatCode
    raise errors.YapfError(errors.FormatErrorMsg(e))
  File "/module/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yapf/yapflib/errors.py", line 37, in FormatErrorMsg
    return '{}:{}:{}: {}'.format(e.args[1][0], e.args[1][1], e.args[1][2], e.msg)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It seems that the error arises from a unicode character from the `lib2to3.pgen2.parse.ParseError: bad token: type=58, value='ִ', context=('', (325, 19))` error, though I am unsure how to 1) find the source of the error and 2) how to fix it if I do find it.

As of now, I don't believe that unicode character is in the codebase; though, the codebase is fairly large so it is entirely possible that I am just missing it somewhere.

Does anyone have any experience parsing these types of errors or can point me in the right direction?

I found a few github issues describing this type of error, but they remain Open with no direction on finding the source.

Comment: error shows you full path to file in which it gets error - so you can open it and add `print()`. `print(type(..))`, `print(len(...))` to see what it gets in variables in this line. Maybe it will show what values make problem.

Comment: errror doesn't show problem with `unicode` - it rather shows that it get data with wrong structure - probably it expects item with 3 values (to display `args[1][0]`, `args[1][1]`, `args[1][2]`) but it gets item with less values.